# How do I access the JSON output of a command using the command line?

Tags: node.js, json, linux, unix, command-line

I'm running a command that contacts a server, and the server outputs JSON through the command to get the data. How do I get the data from the JSON output and use the data? I'm running the command from the command line in Linux.

For example:

```
~/jason$:command xyz
{
  name: "mary"
  eyecolor: "red"
}
```

I thought that maybe putting the command in a variable would put me in the right direction but I don't know where to go from there:

```
result=$(command xyz)
# ...
```

Comment: What do you mean by *"how do I access the output"*? Once it's stored in `result` you *access* it like any other variable, `$result` ...

Comment: Like the keys and values.